# Can't put specific value in a list menu

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a playlist and a player in one script. When click any one of the list it passes a value which i take with GET method(`$_GET['List_id']`) and then play this specific video. But i need a highlighter to highlight the list item which is playing now.
In twitter bootstrap it needs only to declare **class='active'**. So i initialize class blank(`$ive = ''`) and when it matches with `$_GET` values it put active into it. 
But it won't works, With this code all list items show active. How to put this 'active' within `$ive` variable?

Here is my code--

```
<?php
include "ste_content/connect.php";

//initialize
$subID = $_GET['Subcategory_id'];
$listID = $_GET['List_id'];
$list = "";
$ive = '';

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `video_links` WHERE `Subcategory_id`=".       
    $_GET["Subcategory_id"] ." ORDER BY `Subcategory_id`";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $strTitle = $row['List_title'];
    $id = $row['List_id'];

    $strLink = "<a href = 'tv.php?List_id=" . $row['List_id'] 
        . "&&Subcategory_id=". $row['Subcategory_id']."'>" 
        . $strTitle . "</a>";

    if(strcmp($listID,$id)==0){
        $ive = 'active';
    }

    $list .= "<li class='$ive'><a href='#'><i class='icon-chevron-right'></i> $strLink </a></li>" ;  
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

I am output this **$list** variable inside html.

Comment: 1) The MySQL extension is now deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi and don't forget to use prepared statements with bound parameters to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities. 2) You're nesting `<a>` tags by putting `$strLink` in the `$list` concatenation. Probably not what you want. 3) `&&Subcategory_id` should probably only have one ampersand

Comment: I am a newbie and this is my first development project. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the `$ive` variable in each loop or else everything after the first match will be *active*.

Try this

```
$list .= sprintf('<li%s><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> %s </li>',
                 $id == $listID ? ' class="active"' : '', $strLink);
```

Also, you seem to be nesting `<a>` tags with `$strLink` in `$list`. You probably don't want to do that

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have found your code prone to SQL injection, so please take care of this.

The only thing you are missing is you have not initialized the variable $ive, you need to initialize the variable like below inside while loop so that it overrides the value assigned in previous loop.

See second line in below code is the only thing I have added:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
$ive = '';
$strTitle = $row['List_title'];
$id = $row['List_id'];

$strLink = "<a href = 'tv.php?List_id=" . $row['List_id'] . "&&Subcategory_id=".  $row['Subcategory_id']."'>" . $strTitle . "</a>";

if(strcmp($listID,$id)==0){
$ive = 'active';
}

$list .= "<li class='$ive'><a href='#'><i class='icon-chevron-right'></i> $strLink    </a></li>" ;  
}
```